# Homemade frozen pizza dough

Tags: dough, frozen

I like to use the commercial frozen pizza doughs to make pizza, like for example Tizeo's.

The problem is that my doctor has told me to cut out sodium. I used to make my own, but then I would have to bake soon.

What I would like is a techinque where I could make a big batch of pizza dough, split it up into small pieces, freeze it, then pull out some and have to thaw and rise so I can make pizza that day.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the 'Artisan Bread in 5 Minutes a Day' technique lets you keep the dough in your fridge for about 2 weeks ... but they do add a fair bit of salt to keep the yeast from getting too active.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do it all the time.  (but then I cut out gluten ... blah)

- Make the dough
- Let it proof once.
- Roll into smaller balls
- Place in a zip-top container
- Freeze

It's easiest to let it thaw in the fridge overnight when you want to use it ... but because I make lots of small balls (maybe 2" / 5cm across), and then freeze them in sheets (16 to a gallon zip-top bag), if I have to I can break it apart into smaller amounts ... or spread it out so there's additional surface area for thawing.

Once it's thawed, you can easily shape it, and then add toppings and bake.  (or bake, add toppings, and bake ... or cast iron skillet, flip, flip again, top & broil ... however you like baking pizzas)

Comment: This is what I do as well. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

I see Joe suggested a method, but one important thing: don't freeze the balls, make discs and freeze them. You'll have much shorter thawing times that way.

The way I do it is to freeze them laid out separately on different shelves, and once they are hard enough to handle without bending and sticking, put them into a case and store the case.