# Can I freeze bread dough after the first rising?

Tags: bread

The bread dough that I am making calls for it to rise for 1 hour, knead for 5 minutes, then rise for another hour, shape into loaves, rise for 45 minutes, then bake.  So can I freeze the dough after the first rise?

Comment: yes you can; most industrial bakery do that.

Comment: related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/63071/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/14184/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/69450/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/52017/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/73194/67

Comment: I find it easiest in these situations to freeze it as rolls -- a whole loaf takes too long to defrost.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you absolutely can - this is the common way to freeze dough, actually.  It's better to freeze after the first rise.  Often the second rise will be done in the refrigerator along with thawing; and most of the recipes I've seen skip a third rise (so you freeze the dough shaped, and you're rising in shaped form alongside thawing plus a warming stage while you preheat the oven).

See for example [this guide to freezing different doughs](http://dontwastethecrumbs.com/2015/02/ultimate-guide-freezing-bread-dough-baked-goods/); or [King Arthur Flour's article on the subject](http://blog.kingarthurflour.com/2009/11/28/freeze-time-savers-for-the-holidays/).

Answer (score 0):

I here make the dough. Let it rise. Kneed it down. Put it in a bread pan 1/2 full. Let it rise to full. Cover & freeze. Remove when needed. Remove cover. Let thaw. It will start to rise again. Bake it rises a little more. Do the same with pizza crust.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I don't get how this answers the question? If your answer is yes, then please make it more visible. Also, what's the added value? What's new, not yet posted in already existing answer by @JoeM?